# What's the fastest and easiest way to download all the images from a website

Tags: curl, wget

What's the fastest and easiest way to download all the images from a website? More specifically, http://www.cycustom.com/large/.

I'm thinking something along the lines of wget or curl.

To clarify, first (and foremost) I currently do not know how to accomplish this task. Secondly, I'm interested in seeing whether wget or curl has an easier-to-understand solution. Thanks.

--- UPDATE @sarnold---

Thank you for responding. I thought that would do the trick too. However, it does not. Here's the command's output:

```
wget --mirror --no-parent http://www.cycustom.com/large/
--2012-01-10 18:19:36--  http://www.cycustom.com/large/
Resolving www.cycustom.com... 64.244.61.237
Connecting to www.cycustom.com|64.244.61.237|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `www.cycustom.com/large/index.html'

    [  <=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ] 188,795      504K/s   in 0.4s    

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2012-01-10 18:19:37 (504 KB/s) - `www.cycustom.com/large/index.html' saved [188795]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2012-01-10 18:19:37--  http://www.cycustom.com/robots.txt
Connecting to www.cycustom.com|64.244.61.237|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 174 [text/plain]
Saving to: `www.cycustom.com/robots.txt'

100%[======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 174         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2012-01-10 18:19:37 (36.6 MB/s) - `www.cycustom.com/robots.txt' saved [174/174]

FINISHED --2012-01-10 18:19:37--
Downloaded: 2 files, 185K in 0.4s (505 KB/s)
```

Here's a picture of the files created https://img.skitch.com/20120111-nputrm7hy83r7bct33midhdp6d.jpg

My objective is to have a folder full of images files. The following command did not achieve this objective.

```
wget --mirror --no-parent http://www.cycustom.com/large/
```

Comment: @sarnold [Here's a picture of the index.html file created w/ some notes](https://img.skitch.com/20120111-1uapp8upbq6qmtrwsqsiygg62i.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

```
wget --mirror --no-parent http://www.example.com/large/
```

The `--no-parent` prevents it from slurping the entire website.

---

Ahh, I see they have placed a `robots.txt` asking robots to *not* download photos from that directory:

```
$ curl http://www.cycustom.com/robots.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /css/
Disallow: /flash/
Disallow: /large/
Disallow: /pdfs/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /small/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /temp/
$
```

`wget(1)` does not document any method to ignore `robots.txt` and I've never found an easy way to perform the equivalent of `--mirror` in `curl(1)`. If you wanted to continue using `wget(1)`, then you would need to insert an HTTP proxy in the middle that returns `404` for `GET /robots.txt` requests.

I think it is easier to change approach. Since I wanted more experience using [Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/wiki/), here's what I came up with:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.cycustom.com/large/"))

doc.css('tr > td > a').each do |link|
  name = link['href']
  next unless name.match(/jpg/)
  File.open(name, "wb") do |out|
    out.write(open("http://www.cycustom.com/large/" + name))
  end
end
```

This is just a quick and dirty script -- embedding the URL twice is a bit ugly. So if this is intended for long-term production use, clean it up first -- or figure out how to use `rsync(1)` instead.

Comment: Edited the original question to include the results of your suggestion

Answer (score 5):

The `robots.txt` file can be ignored by adding the following option:

```
-e robots=off
```

I also recommend adding an option to slow down the download in order to limit the load on the server. For instance, this options waits 30 seconds between one file and the next:

```
--wait 30
```